# Calling a method on a Ruby module

Tags: ruby

I have the following Ruby code:

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass
    def self.my_method
    end
  end
end
```

To call `my_method`, I enter `MyModule::MyClass.my_method`. I'd like to write a wrapper for `my_method` on the module itself:

```
MyModule.my_method
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simple method:

```
module MyModule
  def self.my_method(*args)
    MyModule::MyClass.my_method(*args)
  end
end
```

Harder method:

Use metaprogramming to write a function for all cases (like attr_accessor).

Comment: I think I know now why it didn't work before: I had the MyModule.my_method declaration in one file (my_module.rb) and the MyModule::MyClass.my_method in another file (my_class.rb). When I put the above method inside my_class.rb, MyModule.my_method worked!

Comment: Easier way: require 'forwardable'.

Answer (score 33):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but: if you make it a regular method and modify it with module_function, you will be able to call it any way you choose.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

module MyModule

  def my_method
    p "my method"
  end
  module_function :my_method

end
```

Having done this, you may either include the module and call the method as an instance method:

```
class MyClass

  include MyModule

  def foo
    my_method
  end

end

MyClass.new.foo      # => "my method"
```

or you may call the method as a class method on the module:

```
MyModule.my_method   # => "my method"
```

Comment: In your case, can you call your method on your module? Don't you need self in front of my_method?

Comment: @Jwan622 I've tried to improve my answer.  Does it answer your question now?

Comment: What is the "better" was `def self.my_method` or `module_function :my_method`? For me both things do the job

Comment: @KargWare `def self.my_method` creates a method that can only be called using `MyModule.my_method`.  Using `module_function :my_method` creates a method that can be called using either `MyModule.my_method`, or 'instance_of_class_including_my_module.my_method`

Answer (score 15):

You can define the method directly inside the module.

```
module MyModule
  def self.my_method
    puts "Hi I am #{self}"
  end
end

MyModule.my_method  #=> Hi I am MyModule
```